# How to choose the roots of 4 different Zadoff-Chu sequences?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, digital-communications

I would like to generate 4 Zadoff-Chu sequences.
The sequence length is 63.
I need to properly choose the roots (r1, r2, r3, and r4) so that:

1. Each root is relatively prime to the sequence length which is 63.
2. The difference between any two roots, e.g., (r1-r2) should also be relatively prime to 63.

Could you please help me to choose the optimum values of the roots? (I need 4 roots).
thanks

Comment: What is a "root" in the context of a Zadoff-Chu sequence? (being constant envelope, they have no zeros); or are these your *root sequences* (which is just, unshifted Zadoff-Chu sequences)? But how could a sequence be relatively prime to a number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is impossible for the second constraint.

As $63=3\times3\times7$, the difference of any two $r_i$ must not be a multiple of $3$. This is equivalent to the remainders of the division of any two $r_i$ by $3$ must be different.

Because we have only three remainders ($0, 1$, and $2$), among the four $r_i$, there must be at least two that have the same remainder and, therefore, their difference is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: +1 _Very_ nice observation.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thank you sir